# MySQL Custom Ordering (datetime and join table)

Tags: mysql, datetime

Let's say I have a list of presentations meant to be played on a given day, following this data structure:

```
ID      DateTime             Title          StreamID
--------------------------------------------------------
2268    2015-07-21 07:45:00  Introduction   NULL
2229    2015-07-21 09:00:00  A              1   
2259    2015-07-21 09:00:00  D              2
2262    2015-07-21 09:00:00  G              3   
2230    2015-07-21 10:00:00  B              1   
2260    2015-07-21 10:00:00  E              2   
2263    2015-07-21 10:00:00  H              3   
2261    2015-07-21 11:00:00  F              2   
2264    2015-07-21 11:00:00  I              3   
2250    2015-07-21 11:00:00  C              1   
2267    2015-07-21 18:00:00  Outro          NULL
```

Some presentations are part of streams, some aren't. Streams are a way of grouping presentations in a parallel manner
(the StreamID is joined as part of my query)

I would like to be able to order them as following: By datetime, but if they are part of a stream, then order presentations by datetime BUT ALSO per stream id FIRST
So like as followed:

```
ID      DateTime             Title          StreamID
--------------------------------------------------------
2268    2015-07-21 07:45:00  Introduction   NULL
2229    2015-07-21 09:00:00  A              1   
2230    2015-07-21 10:00:00  B              1
2250    2015-07-21 11:00:00  C              1   
2259    2015-07-21 09:00:00  D              2
2260    2015-07-21 10:00:00  E              2   
2261    2015-07-21 11:00:00  F              2   
2262    2015-07-21 09:00:00  G              3   
2263    2015-07-21 10:00:00  H              3   
2264    2015-07-21 11:00:00  I              3   
2267    2015-07-21 18:00:00  Outro          NULL
```

Hope that makes sense.

I have tried the following queries but without success:

```
SELECT * FROM presentation
LEFT JOIN stream ON stream.ID = presentation.StreamID
ORDER BY DateTime, StreamID
```

AND

```
SELECT * FROM presentation
LEFT JOIN stream ON stream.ID = presentation.StreamID
ORDER BY StreamID, DateTime
```

Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM presentation AS p 
INNER JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(StreamID, ID) AS ID, MIN(`DateTime`) AS minDate
            FROM presentation
            GROUP BY COALESCE(StreamID, ID))
AS t ON COALESCE(p.StreamID, p.ID) = t.ID
ORDER BY minDate, p.StreamID, p.DateTime
```

The above query employs a derived table that groups records per `StreamID`, or, in case of `NULL`, per `ID`. The minimum `DateTime` is selected for each of these groups. Joining this derived table back to the original table, we can achieve *group sorting*, i.e. sort every group by date, wherein a row with a `NULL` value of `StreamID` is considered as a separate group.

Note: For the sake of simplicity `Stream` table has been left out of the query.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1851/2)

Comment: Works like a charm.
Thanks a lot, Giorgos !